# Submitting jquery dialog box using ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm attempting to do a search using a jquery ui dialog box, and have the results also appear in a dialog box without any redirection on the actual page.  I'm thinking an easy way of doing this is just to create my ui and have a < div id > surrounding the content, then replace the div with a view using an ajax call.

I've gotten the basics of this working, but... I have no clue how to pass the input field parameters to the incoming view/controller!  It's currently not using submit() in any shape or form as this causes an unavoidable page redirect afaik.

My dialog contains standard text fields such as:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<label>Customer Name</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
<label>EIN</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ein, new { @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
<label>State Tax ID Number</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StateTaxId, new { @class = "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
```

I have a placeholder for the dialog div

```
<div id="dialog-searchResults" title="Search Results" class="hide">
@using (Html.BeginForm("searchResults", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "searchResultForm" }))
{
<div id="SearchContents">a</div>
}
</div>
```

The ajax call

```
function InsertDialogDiv(ajaxUrl, divTable) {
var jsonData = {
        "id": 0
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE_URL + ajaxUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        success: function (data) {
            $(divTable).replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $(divTable).replaceWith(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Where ajaxUrl='Customer/SearchResults' as the path of the view.

Replacing the div in this way does trigger the Customer's controller to hit the SearchResults function, but as I'm not submitting, the model has all null values.  How do I get my precious nuggets of information?

TY & Rat's off to ya!

PS: ASP.NET C# MVC4 Razor

Comment: What does your SearchResults action look like? How do you trigger InsertDialogDiv function? Does the SearchContents div contain the fields for Customer Name, EIN, and State Tax ID?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, got it all worked out.   data: $(dialogSubmitted).serialize() was the line I realized I needed, which grabs the input fields and sends them via ajax without a submit call.